# Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, soap

I am getting below error on clicking on checkout button:

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in
>   /home/insighw6/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex.php
>   on line 134

Please help to fix.

Comment: have you enabled compilation? If yes then first disabled compilation admin side, clear all cache and check it is working or not.

Comment: Is the soap module enabled (for php) on your server ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below step

1. Disable Compilation from

   `Admin -> System -> Tools -> Compilation`

Or

2. Go to `System -> Tools -> Compilation and Run Compilation process` again

Comment: its not working..!

Comment: can you try with flush your cache after follow above step ?

Comment: its not working

Comment: copy below path file in  `/includes/src/`
`app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php`